# Let $x \sim y$ if and only if $x-y\in \mathbb{Q}$.Show that the quotient topology on $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is the indiscrete topology.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with standard (Euclidean) topology.

Let
$x \sim y$ if and only if $x-y\in \mathbb{Q}$.

**Show that $\mathbb{R} /\sim$ is uncountable but that the quotient topology on $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is the indiscrete topology.**

To show that $\mathbb{R} /\sim = \{[x] : x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is uncountable, suppose that it is countable.

Then the equivalence classes disjointly partitions $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $[x] = \{y\in \mathbb{R} : y\sim x\} = \{x+q: q\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is countable, therefore $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable union of countable set. Since countable union of countable set is countable, $\mathbb{R}$ is then countable and this is a contradiction. Hence $\mathbb{R} /\sim = \{[x] : x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is uncountable.

To show that the quotient topology on $\mathbb{R} /\sim$ is the indiscrete topology, let's prove that for any nontrivial strict open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R} /\sim$, we have $$\bigcup_{[x]\in U} [x]$$ being closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

When $U$ is finite, it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ since each $[x]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and finite union of closed sets is closed. 
However, I am not sure how to complete the proof when $U$ is any arbitrary subset.

Comment: Just sayin: you dont have to show that this union is closed. You only have to show that it is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to see ($\mathbb Q$ is dense!) that any non-empty open interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb R$ contains a representative of each equivalence class. Thus $\pi^{-1}(U)$ can only be open if $U=\emptyset$ or $U=\mathbb R/ \sim$.

Comment: First ;) ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

A different attempt:

1. Recall that a set in $\mathbb{R} / \sim$ is open iff its preimage under the projection is open.
2. Show that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a representative of every residue class.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $U$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}/\sim$. Let $\pi: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}/\sim$ be given by $\pi(x) = [x]$. Consider the set $V = \pi^{-1}(U)$. Let $x\in U$. By the definition of the quotient topology, $V$ is open in \mathbb{R}, and so let $(a,b)$ be an interval which is a subset of $V$ containing $\pi^{-1}(x)$. However, note that $(a,b)$ contains a representative for every equivalent class with respect to $\sim$. It follows that $U = \mathbb{R}/\sim$, and so this space has the indiscrete topology.